# Magento keeps redirecting to default website for a multisite store

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, ubuntu-14.04

We have 3 website in a Magento store.
Here's what I've done.

1. I have downloaded the code from the live site to my local machine
2. set up the vhost for the 3 websites

   ```
   created site1(2 & 3).com.conf and enabled them
   ```
3. Added the corresponding lines to /etc/hosts
4. In my .htaccess I have the code that manages the 3 websites

   ```
   SetEnvIf Host www\.site1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=site1
   SetEnvIf Host www\.site1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
   SetEnvIf Host ^site1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=site1
   SetEnvIf Host ^site1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
   SetEnvIf Host www\.site2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=site2
   SetEnvIf Host www\.site2\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
   SetEnvIf Host ^site2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=site2
   SetEnvIf Host ^site2\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
   SetEnvIf Host www\.site3\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=site3
   SetEnvIf Host www\.site3\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
   SetEnvIf Host ^site3\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=site3
   SetEnvIf Host ^site3\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
   ```

Everything is working fine on the live server but on my local machine when I type www.site1.com or www.site2.com I'm automatically redirected to www.site2.com as it's the default website.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 I've just set up the whole environment (apache2, php5, mysql) as my machine was formatted last week.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems something is wrong with my Apache configuration.

```
SetEnvIf Host returns an empty value
```

I switched to setting the values in each of my vhosts

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "site1"
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"
```

The only difference between local and production is Apache version 2.4 in local and 2.2 in production

Answer (score 0):

did you change url for each website.Please check core_config_data table or you can change it in admin.

```
admin->system->configuration->general->web->(Secure and unsecure Url)
```

Comment: These are the same urls that I have in the live server. I kept everything. I think it's something to do with my configuration but I can't figure out what exactly.